# iOS App Store Rating History

Tags: ios-appstore

I want to find my iOS app star rating history, based on older build versions.

I'm able to view previous Reviews via iTunes Connect but it doesn't show the rating history.

e.g: current build(v3.0) is 4 out of 5 stars, what's the old build (v2.9) star rating.

I have Google Analytics, but I'm also unable to find app rating.